# ACPI BIOS ERROR (BUG): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTO._GTF.DSSP] AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)

Tags: boot, 18.04

My Ubuntu 18.04 system has been working fine for quite some time (a few years). It suddenly threw up this error. Causes the system to auto-reboot several time. Sometimes it is able to boot into the login but even after login, it is behaving in a cranky manner. What gives?

linux kernel  5.4.0-42-generic

[image: Error]

**Update:**

1. The BIOS was updated and that resolved the crazy auto-reboot issue and made the system usable.
2. I found that this Error appears in the dmesg log of both 18.04 and 16.04. Below is a more detailed list of the ACPI error msg (I found some related ACPI msgs was issued but without the ACPI syntax). **It seems the issue pertains to the method _GTF. What is that and what does it do? Also, what is a DSSP?**

More details from dmesg on the error:

```
[    1.201570] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT0._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[    1.201575] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]
[    1.201576] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]
[    1.201577] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT0._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-531)
[    1.205307] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT0._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[    1.205311] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]
[    1.205312] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]
[    1.205313] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT0._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-531)
[    1.249944] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT1._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[    1.249949] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]
[    1.249950] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]
[    1.249951] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT1._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-531)
[    1.333524] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT1._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[    1.333529] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]
[    1.333530] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]
[    1.333531] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT1._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-531)
```

Comment: If this happened after a kernel upgrade, you could try to boot from the previous kernel.

Comment: Any progres on that @sun-bear ?

Comment: I'm also wondering... Have the same error on my Dell XPS 13 (9310). It suddenly crashes from nowhere. :/

Comment: @somenxavier and DanielHansson Unfortunately not.

Comment: @SunBear Can we triage the bug? How would we do that?

Comment: @somenxavier What does "triage the bug" means?

Comment: @SunBear Debug the bug with system variables and symbols (eg. output of some files or processes)

Comment: This problem was on my old dell laptop but it never had crazy auto reboots

Answer (score 13):

I found a detailed explanation of this problem [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171228022907/https://blog.le-vert.net/?p=24):
To make a long story short (code highlighting my own):

> The proper fix is simply to boot your kernel with `libata.noacpi=1`
> and resume works again, YAY \o/
>
> To make it permanent on Debian, edit `/etc/default/grub` and set the
> following line:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="libata.noacpi=1"
> ```
>
> Then regenerate grub config by running `update-grub`.

Comment: There was already a value under `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Should i replace it or add a new line with the new values posted in your answer?

Comment: There must be just one GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAUT line. Just add the string to the content of that line. If that line is empty (it should be empty by default), that means ="" just replace the line.

Comment: It worked for me... I'm on MxLinux 21 (KDE)

Comment: It worked for me. I'm on Debian 11

Comment: It solved my internet issue. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04