# Dell vostro 5625 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol

Tags: boot, 20.04, dell, 22.04

Good morning.
I have an issue with Dell Vostro 5625 based on Ryzen 7 and Ubuntu (20.04, 22.04) with the newest kernel version.
During the login I see this error:
ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_.SB.PCI0.LPC0.ECO], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
System starts but after suspend or close the lid dont wanna wake up
How to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 2 unrelated issues. You can ignore the messages on start up many have them right now.  The does not want to wake is the only thing you may want to fix. Many also have that and no I do not know how to correct it. BTW an actual kernel version would be a good idea. If someone reads this even a few months from now the kernel may be newer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI BIOS ERROR (BUG): Could not resolve symbol \[\‌\_SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTO.\_GTF.DSSP\] AE\_NOT\_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272026/acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-sb-pcio-sato-prto-gtf-dssp)

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem, u can just install this:

```
sudo apt install linux-oem-22.04c
```

and reboot laptop, after reboot problem was solved. I hope this will help to you too.

This is worked for me, same laptop vostro 5625 with ryzen 7 on Ubuntu budgie 22.04.2.