# ACPI BIOS Error in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, acpi

This is the error I am getting after choosing the booting option as Ubuntu. Then, I am getting the following error. I am not able to boot into the Ubuntu. What could be the reason my BIOS is already up-to-date, as windows is working perfectly fine.

[image: Screen photo]

Comment: The messages in the screen shot are not errors they are info messages.  As for why Ubuntu will not boot it is not because of these messages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272026/acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-sb-pcio-sato-prto-gtf-dssp