# ACPI BIOS Error(bug): Failure creating named object [ \_SB.PCIO.GPPO.VGA], AE_ALREADY EXISTS(20210730/dswload2-326) in HP AMD ryzen 7 laptop

Tags: boot, 20.04, bios, acpi

I have HP AMD Ryzen 7 laptop and recently installed a dual boot mode of Windows 10 and  Ubuntu 20.04. Most of the time I'm using Ubuntu. Nowadays I'm getting an ACPI Bios Error during GRUB booting and restarting again and again. I selected Advanced option for Ubuntu listed in GNU GRUB menu updated `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intremap=off"` in `/etc/default/grub` and rebooted my system. Now I can login to my Ubuntu operating system, but each and every time I'm performing this when I restart my system which is very much annoying. Is there any permanent solution for this ACPI Boot error?

```
ACPI BIOS Error(bug): Failure creating named object [ \_SB.PCIO.GPPO.VGA], AE_ALREADY EXISTS(20210730/dswload2-326) \n
ACPI Error:AE_ALREADT_EXISTS,During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220) \n
ACPI BIOS Error(bug): Failure creating named object [ \_SB.PCIO.GPPO.VGA], AE_ALREADY EXISTS(20210730/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error:AE_ALREADT_EXISTS,During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
/dev/nvme0n1p8:recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p8:clean,275312/9945088 file....................*
```

Comment: This has been answered several times: no. The notice is benign, is not the cause of a hangup, All it is is a mismatch between the bios and the kernel where the bios does not live up to its specifications. By the way: we all get these since as of kernel 5.19 the kernel devs decided to show these (before that they got suppressed).

Comment: duplicates: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367947/acpi-error-messages-during-boot  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272026/acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-sb-pcio-sato-prto-gtf-dssp

Comment: In case you want to reword this question to the "intremap=off":  do you have a Intel 5500, 5520, or X58 chipset?  If so those chipsets have serious bugs. See dmesg. It shoud have "[Hardware Error]: This system BIOS has enabled interrupt remapping
on a chipset that contains an errata making that feature unstable.  Please reboot with intremap=off added to the kernel command line and contact your BIOS vendor for an update"

Answer (score 0):

That same bug occur to me on Ubuntu 22.04, after update a Nvidia drivers. Solution was a open system in recovery mode,  purge a nvidia drivers and install opensorce driver: X.org.x server instead of nvidia driver 525 which I instal before problem. I use this solution [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)