# ACPI BIOS error on each boot

Tags: boot

I have a Windows laptop. I have installed Ubuntu, not as a dual boot, and every time I boot I get this error:

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1272026

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04 "ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol" errors on Asus X705UA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416198/ubuntu-22-04-acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-errors-on-asus-x7)